# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar with Non Rectangular Header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on website and i am thinking if it is possible to create a bootstrap navbar with Non Rectangular header as a background.

The Header should look something similar to this:

[image]

Can you suggest some idea how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is by using the :before and :after selectors, see an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ej68c05/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Company</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.header {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#cc4f4f;
  padding:16px;
}
.header:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#cc4f4f;
}
.header:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:100px;
  border:15px solid #cc4f4f;
  border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
  border-right:40px solid transparent;
}
.header h1 {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

The :before selector creates a solid block, and the :after selector creates a slanted block using mixed borders. Adding borders to an element with a width/height of 0px and changing the colours of certain sides allows you to create a slanted effect, as each border is coming out from a single point.

You can find more info on the :before/:after selectors here:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/